# make image expand on click to no larger than browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am trying to utilize some javascript so that a user can click on a few thumbnail images and each will display larger.

I have some code that works, but there are 3 things I can't figure out how to accomplish. In order of importance.

1 - the image should not display larger than the browser window. Currently I have a fairly large image, and a really small resolution would cause this to display larger than the browser and cut off part of the image.

2 - I'd like to set a max size to the image as well, so it won't end up huge. Currently it fills the screen until one dimension (vertical or horizontal) is at least maxed out.

3 - I'd like there to be some formatting that suggested to the user how to close it. I can manually add text to each image saying "click anywhere to close", but I'd rather not have to edit the images.

PS - apologies that I don't know the right terms for things.

What I have now:

Javascript

```
        function showImage(smSrc, lgSrc) {
            document.getElementById('largeImg').src = smSrc;
            showLargeImagePanel();
            unselectAll();
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('largeImg').src = lgSrc;
            }, 0)
        }
        function showLargeImagePanel() {
            document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.display= 'block';
        }
        function unselectAll() {
            if(document.selection) document.selection.empty();
            if(window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
```

and the css/html

```
<style type="text/css">#largeImgPanel {
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
        }
```

```
<p>Please click on each image thumbnail to enlarge. Click again to return to this view.</p>
<br />
<img onclick="showImage(this.src, 'http://surveygizmolibrary.s3.amazonaws.com/library/75649/C2ErrorComparisonA.png');" src="http://surveygizmolibrary.s3.amazonaws.com/library/75649/C2ErrorComparisonAThumb.png" style="cursor: pointer; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;" />               <br />
<br />
<img onclick="showImage(this.src, 'http://surveygizmolibrary.s3.amazonaws.com/library/75649/C2ErrorComparisonB.png');" src="http://surveygizmolibrary.s3.amazonaws.com/library/75649/C2ErrorComparisonBThumb.png" style="cursor: pointer; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;" />               <br />
<br />
<img onclick="showImage(this.src, 'http://surveygizmolibrary.s3.amazonaws.com/library/75649/C2ErrorComparisonC.png');" src="http://surveygizmolibrary.s3.amazonaws.com/library/75649/C2ErrorComparisonCThumb.png" style="cursor: pointer; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid;" />
```

Comment: where is the #largeImgPanel in your html and how is it done? that is the interesting part

Comment: css is your friend for all of this probaly. You're going to want to add and remove a class on click. First I would suggest looking at the css position property. That will allow you among other things to do floating text positioned over your image (solving number 3). For 1 and 2 your probably going to want to look at css max-width and max-height. Finally if your using this long term I would look into getting a js library, depending on what your doing you can go anywhere from simple to complex. Based on what you have here I would recommend jquery to simplify dom manipulation.

Comment: @user6292372 showImage calls showlargeImgPanel, which uses largeImgPanel

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

Try this:

```
#largeImgPanel img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

## 2:

Try this:

```
#largeImgPanel img {
  max-width: (insert whatever you want here)px;
  max-height: (insert whatever you want here)px;
}
```

## 3:

A good way to do this is using `position: absolute`. For each of your images you should make a container around the image and set it to `position: relative`. Inside of the container, along with the image, you should have a text tag that is `position: absolute` wherever you want it to be.

For example, this code would put the image text in the top left corner of the image.

**html**

```
<div class='img-container'>
  <img src='img.jpg'/>
  <p class='img-text'>Text for image</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.img-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```